# Create/Destroy New Environment in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, environment

I'm trying to find a method whereby a PowerShell script can be executed without the environment "*leaking*" back-and-forth between the script and other scripts/the console.

I.e. if I set an environment variable before I call the script, I don't want the script to see that environment variable, and if I set an environment variable in the script, I don't want to be able to see it from the console afterwards.

I'm building PowerShell build/compile script that invokes *vcvarsall.bat* (to get all the Visual C++ 2010 variables etc. into the environment), but I don't want the environment that *vcvarsall.bat* creates "*leaking*" back onto the console -- I want to start fresh each time without closing/re-opening the PowerShell window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the script using:

```
powershell.exe -file <PS1 File>
```

Current variables will not be available in the PS1 script and variables created in the PS1 script will not be available after it exits.

Comment: To be clear, when you launch one process from another, the new process will inherit the environment of its parent at the time it was created. This means that environment variables created in the console *will* appear in the script's environment, though any environment changes in the script will not be propagated back into the parent (compare the output of the `dir` calls in the example: `$env:v1,$env:v2 = 'alpha','beta'; dir env:v*; powershell { $env:v2,$env:v3 = 'beta2','gamma'; dir env:v* }; dir env:v*`).